# Batch file for checking system proxy

Tags: batch-file, proxy

I need a batch file to check that the PC is using a proxy server or not and give me a yes or no result.
I've already read about batch files enabling or disabling proxies but i want a batch file to check that am I using a proxy or not and give me the yes or no result.

Comment: I'll be glad to have it on XP vista and 7 OS.

Answer (score 2):

command to show proxy settings:

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

---

to set a proxy server:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy myproxy
```

---

to set `direct access` without proxy:

```
netsh winhttp reset proxy
```

Comment: thanx for your reply.
I just tested it on my X64 windows Vista and it doesn't work.
I set a proxy and used your first command and it says no proxy-direct access.
any help would be appreciated.